# MahApps.Metro DynamicResource colours not being applied

Tags: mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps styles in an Excel document pane. They work fine on my Excel 2013 and on Excel 2010 on a standalone machine. However we have a virtual machine which seems to have a group policy applied that is causing some issues.

Looking at the styles in the master branch, I see references to NormalForegroundBrush but I can't find this in the Colours.xaml file. A search on the MahApps GitHub shows it was added over a year ago, but now appears to be missing from the master branch. I am wondering if this and maybe other missing styles are what is causing my problems.

A combobox whose dropdowns have a white background, appear with a black background. I tried setting the background using DynamicResource WhiteBrush but this had no effect. If I specifically set it to "White" then that works. I'm puzzled.

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 1):

MahApps has heavily changed lately. Especially the errors with wrong color declarations are gone. Try either to use the new version from NuGet or clone the newest build from [github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)